# Random probability for internet connection

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

An internet service provider has two connection lines for its customers.
$80\%$ of customers are connected through Line $I$, the rest through Line $II$.
Line $I$ has a $\operatorname{Gamma}(3, 1/2)$ connection time (in minutes), while Line $II$ has a $U(20, 50)$ connection time (in seconds).
Find the probability that it takes a randomly selected customer more than $30$ seconds to connect to the internet.

Can somebody give me some ideas, please?

Comment: In gamma dist'n is 1/2 a rate or a scale parameter? What is it's mean? 6 or 1.5. (There is no standard parameterization of gamma; you always have to say what parameters are.)

Comment: No response to request re gamma parameter. Did it both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @tommik's (+1) notation:

Assuming the second gamma parameter is rate $1/2$  (the parameterization used in R, where `pgamma` is a gamma CDF) we have $p_1 = 0.9978.$

```
p.1 = 1 - pgamma(.5, 3, .5);  p.1
[1] 0.9978385
```

Also, $p_2 = 0,6667.$

```
p.2 = 1 - punif(30, 20, 50);  p.2
[1] 0.6666667
```

So the answer is $0.9316.$

```
.8*p.1 + .2*p.2
[1] 0.9316041
```

*Note:* If the second gamma parameter is scale $1/2,$ then
$p.1s$ and the answer are shown below:

```
p.1s = 1 - pgamma(.5, 3, 2);  p.1s
[1] 0.9196986
.8*p.1s + .2*p.2
[1] 0.8690922
```

Simulation of a million randomly chosen customers, using the scale=0.5 and rate=2 for gamma is shown below.
Answers agree with analytic answers above to about 2 or 3
significant digits.

```
set.seed(1211)
w1 = rgamma(10^6, 3, 2)
summary(w1)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.006194 0.862998 1.336863 1.499468 1.960694 9.960564 
mean(w1 > .5)
[1] 0.919711
w2 = runif(10^6, 2/6, 5/6)
summary(w2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.3333  0.4586  0.5837  0.5835  0.7085  0.8333 
mean(x2 > .5)
[1] 0.666537
b = rbinom(10^6, 1, .8)
mean(b)
[1] 0.799963
w.c = b*x1 + (1-b)*x2
mean(w.c > .5)
[1] 0.869234
summary(w.c)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.005825 0.661970 1.097923 1.317951 1.775212 9.690274
```

Histograms for simulated waiting times are shown below. Vertical
red lines are at 0.5 min.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
 hist(w1, prob=T, br=60, xlim=c(0,10))
  abline(v=.5, col="red")
 hist(w2, prob=T, br=seq(2/6,5/6,len=10), xlim=c(0,10))
  abline(v=.5, col="red")
 hist(w.c, prob=T, br=60, xlim=c(0,10))
  abline(v=.5, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

What have  you tried? It is simply to apply Total Probability theorem.

$$0.80\times p_1+0.20\times p_2$$

where $p_1,p_2$ are calculated with the given probability distributions.

---

note that Gamma distribution can be expressed in terms of $\chi^2$ to get a numerical result.

---

Please show also what do you mean as Gamma density because there is more than one parametrization.